# How do I adjust text hover color within an <a> element?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

This is controlling text hover color on my entire site.

```
a:hover{color: #4B9397;}
```

I have "a" elements and I want to overwrite the text hover color in them. See below for setup

```
<a href="/link.html">
<div class="event-item">
<img src="../image.jpg"/>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>Link Text</p>
</div>
</a>
```

I tried this and it didn't work.

```
event-item a:hover{color: #newcolor;}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards and missing a `.`

```
a:hover .event-item { color: #newcolor; }
```

---

I would recommend doing this:

```
<a href="/link.html" class="event-item">
    <img src="../image.jpg"/>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Link Text</p>
</a>
```

---

```
a.event-item { display: block; }
a.event-item:hover { color: #newcolor; }
```

Comment: Syntax is hard... Thanks!

Comment: Oh wow why didn't I think of that. Less code, cleaner. Thanks!

Question though, why would I need to reference
    a.event-item { display: block; }

wouldn't .event-item without the a in front work the same?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need it but someone looking at this later will realize this styling should only apply to `a` tags and not any element